# Javascript if string matches array property reorder array with it at 0 position

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, rxjs, reactive-programming

Im using an Angular 5 pipe to process an array before output to ngFor.

My array contains all the active users and I want it to always have the user thats currently logged-in to be at position 0 of the array so that it displays first in the ngFor output.

I can sort alphabetically desc/asc but I cant seem to figure out a solid way to do this..

A pipe might be the wrong way to go about it maybe using filter in some way on the observable before it outputs to the main page is the right way to go but again Im not sure about how to implement that.

My observable is output here by:

```
getActiveUsers(): Observable<iUser[]> {
  return this.db.collection<iUser>('users').valueChanges().catch(this.catchError);                 
}
```

subscribe happens here in my component

```
    this.auth.getActiveUsers().subscribe( async usersAvailable => {
      this.usersFetched = usersAvailable
  }, error => console.log(error));
```

displays in the component html here (with pipe being fed current users id for comparisons within it)

```
  <ion-row *ngFor="let i of rows">
    <div class="o-userGrid__item" (click)="openItem(u)" *ngFor="let u of usersFetched | filterActive: { activeUser: activeAccount }" width-33>
      <img [src]="u?.photoURL" />
      <div class="o-userGrid__title">
        {{ u?.displayName }}
      </div>
    </div>
  </ion-row>
```

and my filterActive pipe is fed the current users id here:

```
filterActive: { activeUser: activeAccount }
```

What's left of my pipe is the following. As mentioned I've tried some sort methods like alphabetically organising etc but of course thats not what I need, so to reiterate: I need the pipe to have the user, whose id matches the active user id, fed into the pipe to be at the first output on the page or position [0] of the array

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'filterActive',
})
export class FilterActivePipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(array: Array<string>, args?: any): Array<string> {  

    // console.log("indexOf ", array.indexOf(args.activeUser) );

  return  array.sort( (a:any, b:any) => {

      console.log("arrayoutput ", b);    
      if( b.uid == args.activeUser ) {

        console.log("active user found ", b.uid + " " + args.activeUser);  
      }      

      return b;
    });


  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it in the end with the following pipe:

```
  import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

  @Pipe({
    name: 'filterActive',
  })
  export class FilterActivePipe implements PipeTransform {

    transform(array: Array<string>, args?: any): Array<string> {  
      array.unshift( 
        array.splice( 
          array.findIndex( (item:any) => item.uid === args.activeUser), // move the active user to the first position in the array
        1)[0]
      )
      return array;    
    }
  }
```